# way to reinitialize a page each time it is shown

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have some pages which are filled dynamically by content loaded with Ajax. My problem is that each time I go to this page, the old content is still there if it hasn't been replaced by new content...

I've thought about 2 home solutions like:

- Creating a "template" page. By calling "pagebeforeshow", I'll copy the code from the template in the target page, and add there the dynamic content...
- Each DOM where dynamic content must be put into, I had a class "clearcache" and by calling "pagebeforeshow" I do a $(".clearcache").empty();

I don't know how to deal with that. Have you ever got the same issue?

---

EDIT:

```
<a href="#PageBlock" data-ajax="false" block-id="5" data-transition="flip"></a>
```

I bind the "tap" event to store the block-id into localstorage, to load dynamic content in the #PageBlock
Everything works very well (tap event, localstorage for the var, ajax loading). The issue comes really when I go from block to other blocks. The new content overwrite old content instead of beginning from a new "blank" page.

For example I have a list where I append datas I get from Ajax. If I switch to another block, the list is completed and not refreshed..

I could do something like empty the list, and then appending content, but I'd like something better because I have several pages/lists/dom like that...

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I click on a location link on a page which shows a map. The heading of the location on the map is set correctly as this comes from the model, but I need to run some javascript which sets the new marker. I'm having a lot of trouble working out how to run the javascript with the updated location.

Comment: could you edit your question and add some code on how you're transitioning from page to page?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where the new contents where not shown on the page when i tried to append it.There is a simple solution where you can just replace append with prepend. 
Example: 
Replace 
$("#divid").append(content) 
with 
$("#divid") .prepend(content)